# How to correctly point tkinter towards an image in a different folder?

Tags: python, tkinter, operating-system

I am creating a tkinter application in which I am using custom button images, along with a custom button class in order for the button to have a hovering effect. The script was working fine when the images and scripts were in the same folder, however,  as soon as I tried using the "os" or "path" module, python gives me this error.

**"_tkinter.TclError: image "N:\Year 13\Computer Science\Project\AMFC\Project files/Buttons/App button.gif" doesn't exist"**

I made sure that the image is actually existent in the path, and I tried building the path based on the "os.getcwd()" and "os.path.join" as well as the "path" module equivalent. I also tried building the absolute path to the image, however, it still didn't work.

```
work_folder = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
button_path = os.path.join(work_folder, "Project files/Buttons")
```

Here is my custom button class:

```
class Button(tk.Button):
    def __init__(self, parent, default_background="", hover_background="", **kwargs):
        tk.Button.__init__(self, master=parent, **kwargs)
        self.default_background = tk.PhotoImage(file=default_background)
        self.hover_background = tk.PhotoImage(file=hover_background)
        self.configure(image=self.default_background)
        self.bind("<Enter>", self.on_enter)
        self.bind("<Leave>", self.on_leave)

    def on_enter(self, event):
        self.configure(image=self.hover_background)

    def on_leave(self, event):
        self.configure(image=self.default_background)
```

Here is how I apply it:

```
import Customised_Widgets as cw    

cw.Button(self, text="Pure Core", default_background=os.path.join(button_path, "App button.gif"),
              hover_background=os.path.join(button_path, "Project files/Buttons/App button(hover).gif"),
              relief=tk.FLAT,highlightcolor="#E7E6E6",highlightbackground="#E7E6E6",
              bg="#E7E6E6", bd=0, padx=0, pady=0, borderwidth=0,
              highlightthickness=0, compound="center").place(x=434, y=270)
```

I created the button in a separate module in order to keep my work more organised. This separate module is in the same folder as the main script.

I don't know what to do, I tried giving the full path name to the image, it still didn't work. It refuses to detect the image in the folder that I point tkinter to, even though it does exist...

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I would define your path outside of your button for readability.

Comment: You seem to be using both `/` and `\` in the path. That might be part of the problem. The simple fact is, if you give python a valid path it will find the file. If it says it can't find the file, you're giving an invalid path.

Comment: Thank you both for your replies. I have defined the path in a variable outside my button for better readability, and also all of the slashes are the same throughout the path. I have checked if the path exists with os.path.exists(), and it returned true. I don't know what else to do...

Comment: `button_path` already includes `Project files/buttons`, so should `hover_background=os.path.join(button_path, "Project files/Buttons/App button(hover).gif")` be `hover_background=os.path.join(button_path, "App button(hover).gif")`?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use the Separator characters in the `os.path.join`. This method will use the correct separator for your path. It is different on different Operation systems (For `Windows`, it’s ‘\’ and for `Unix` it’s ‘/’). Furthermore you can write a cross-platform software with this solution.

You should try the following implementation:

```
os.path.join(button_path, "Project files", "Buttons", "App button(hover).gif")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I have done this throughout the program, and it still says the file doesn't exist. I have even check with os.exists path for constructed paths, and it returns true, however, I still get the error that the path doesn't exist... Any other suggestions?